# Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для записи

Tags: c++

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

struct car 
{
    std::string color;
    char* serialNumber;
    char* registrationNumber;
    std::string numberOfDoors;
    std::string manufactYear;
    std::string type;
    std::string price;
};

int main()
{
    car myCar;

    std::cout << "Enter color: ";
    std::cin >> myCar.color;

    std::cout << "Enter a serial number: ";
    std::cin >> myCar.serialNumber;
    

    return 0;
}
```

Вызывается исключение. При вводе `myCar.color` его нет, но он возникает после ввода `myCar.serialNumber`. В чем же ошибка?

Comment: ```myCar.color``` - строка. А ```myCar.serialNumber```? Куда Вы записываете вводимые данные?

Comment: Я следую тому, что мне пишет компилятор. Конечная цель - измерить количество символов в `myCar.serialNumber`, а компилятор запрещает мне это делать со строкой, только с `char*`

Comment: Как это — запрещает? не может этого быть. Если хотите работать с `char*`, то вы должны выделить память, куда писать данные. Сейчас вы пишете в какое-то случайное место.

Comment: Если в структуре `serialNumber` обозначен как `string`, то при вызове `strlen(myCar.serialNumber)` выводится сообщение "Не существует подходящей функции для преобразования `std::string` в `const char*`"

Comment: Используйте `strlen(myCar.serialNumber.c_str())`, а еще лучше `myCar.serialNumber.lenght()`, при условии что `serialNumber` - это `string`.

Comment: Большое спасибо, все заработало!